# Weight of fan on scales facing down and turned on

Tags: forces, gravity

If I took a fan, placed it on some scales facing down, and turned it on, would the scales read more or less?

Comment: Do you have any initial thoughts on the matter?

Comment: If the fan is acting on the air, then the air is reacting on the fan also. You can work it out using Newton's laws.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on what happens to the air being propelled by the fan, as it passes the pan of the balance.

If the net air flow is around the pan of the balance and continuing ***downward***, then the overall effect will be to force air downward, and thus lift the fan and pan upward.  The balance will read ***less***.

If the blast of air deflects off the pan and winds up flowing ***upward***, then the overall effect will be to force air upward, and thus force the fan and pan downward.  The balance will read ***more***.

One hopes that any deflection of air horizontally will be uniform in all directions